# How do you stop IIS 6.0 using port 443?

Tags: iis, iis-6

I have IIS serving a web app on port 80

and also have another app  Visual SVN server which uses 443.  IIS if it starts first, takes this port even though nothing is configured to use it.

so how do I stop it from using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit the site bindings and remove the SSL identities:

[alt text http://www.bunkerhollow.com/blogs/matt/IIS6MultipleSites2.PNG](http://www.bunkerhollow.com/blogs/matt/IIS6MultipleSites2.PNG)

But first you need to remove the requirement for the web site to use SSL encryption, if it's active:

[image]
<sub>(source: [donkitchen.com](http://www.donkitchen.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/01/require-ssl.png))</sub>

Comment: when I tried this I couldn't remove the SSL one...  not sure why

Comment: Answer edited. And this comment is a bit longer than needed in order to satisfy the 15-characters minimum length.

Comment: awesome...... and I will just say you are awesome again to satisfy the 15 characters minimum length

Answer (score 0):

after a bit of a look...

in C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts  there is a script called adsutil.vbs

cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc//securebindings ""

where the website id is found by going to IIS admin ->  Website properties -> Website -> in the section "Enable Logging" select "Properties" then :-

there's the logfile name W3SVC\exyymmdd.log

in my case, it was 1.